# What functional language implementations allow threads to run in parallel?

Tags: functional-programming, parallel-processing

The OCaml GC imposes a global lock that prevents mutators (threads) from running in parallel although they can run concurrently (interleaved). I believe the same is true of SML/NJ and MLton but not PolyML, GHC, F#, Clojure and Scala.

What other functional language implementations allow threads to run in parallel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm happy to tell you that you're right and that F#, being based on the CLR, doesn't suffer from that limitation at all, and instead benefits from multithreading specific features including [async workflows](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!194.entry), [the mailboxprocessor](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp.core/microsoft.fsharp.control.type_mailboxprocessor-1.html), and the wonderful upcoming (.NET 4.0) Task Parallel Library.

Answer (score 11):

There are a number of good implementations out there.  At the moment, the Haskell people seem to be getting the best results (see [ICFP 2009 paper by Simon Marlow and others](http://www.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/multicore-ghc.pdf) as well as [Haskell Symposium 2009 paper by Donnie Jones and others](http://www.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/threadscope.pdf)).  Erlang is quite close behind, especially if you want to go distributed.

In six to twelve months the answers may have changed :-)

Comment: Those Haskell results are worthless: their parallel implementations are often orders of magnitude slower than most serial implementations.

Comment: @Jon: where's your evidence?

Comment: Compare the performance measurements quoted in the papers you cited with equivalent programs written in other languages. For example, the second paper gives performance results for parallel quicksort (~14s to sort only 100k ints) that are 100x slower than a decent solution in most other languages. You can also benchmark their parallel programs yourself. I did an exhaustive study of Saynte's naive parallelization applied to four of Lennart's Haskell implementations of my ray tracer and found that one stopped scaling at 6 cores and all of the others stopped scaling at only 5 cores.

Comment: In comparison, I have written parallel linear algebra codes in F# that outperform the vendor-tuned Fortran in the Intel MKL when running on Intel hardware.

Answer (score 6):

Haskell [supports parallel threads](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.4/html/users_guide/concurrent-and-parallel.html) via [Data Parallel Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Data_Parallel_Haskell)

Comment: Data Parallel Haskell is still quite experimental, but the parallel thread support in your first link is much more mature. DPH is implemented with parallel threads, not vice versa.

Answer (score 6):

Scala and Clojure are both running on the JVM, which allows real concurrency without any single point of contention bottlenecks.

Comment: Can you recommend a link to anything about parallel programming in Scala?

Comment: Scala supports Actors http://www.scala-lang.org/node/242 if you like that model, and you can use java.util.concurrency just as you would in Java. I suppose given the question is about functional programming, Actors is more appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Erlang implements its own processes and process schedule and allows thousands, tens of thousands and even millions of Erlang processes (inside a single Operating System process).

In SMP and multi-core machines the Erlang Virtual Machine will allocate as many OS threads and OS processes to its process scheduler and process queue to maximise its use of underlying concurrent operations in the hardware architecture.

The concurrency paradigm exposed to the applications remains the same, of course.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Haskell, you can run processes concurrently in Erlang (Concurrency-Oriented Programming) and you can also do so in F# using [.NET Parallel Extensions](http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2009/02/23/adding-parallel-extensions-to-f.aspx) and [Asynchronous Workflows](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2007/10/11/introducing-f-asynchronous-workflows.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Just some additions to confirm further parts of the speculative list:

- Poly/ML supports native threads (POSIX threads or Windows threads) since version 5.2 (from 2006).  Current Poly/ML 5.5 (summer 2012) has improved support for parallel memory management: some of the GC phases use multiple threads, there is special support for online sharing of immutable values to reduce memory footprint of huge applications.
- Isabelle/ML provides an add-on future library for Poly/ML threads.  Isabelle is an interactive theorem prover, but it is integrated with an augmented version SML based on Poly/ML.

Answer (score 0):

python is not a particularly functional language, and with the GIL, it's not very parallel, either, but combined with the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) module (standard since 2.6), you get both, but it's not quite as elegant as pure functional languages.

[Brief example:](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes
    result = pool.apply_async(f, [10])     # evaluate "f(10)" asynchronously
    print result.get(timeout=1)           # prints "100" unless your computer is *very* slow
    print pool.map(f, range(10))          # prints "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
```

Comment: I didn't expect this response to be terribly popular, but please explain a bit what you find so objectionable about this technique?

Comment: My question was specifically about threads and not processes.

Comment: CPython has an issue involving concurrent kernel threads, preventing it's full use.  the multiprocessing module allows you to use a nearly identical interface with processes instead of threads to achieve nearly identical results.  This issue is not present in other flavours of python because they lack the GIL.

Comment: I know. OCaml has the same issue. That is exactly what I'm trying to get away from! :-)